# opencv-python window not staying open in wsl

Tags: opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the following code in WSL on VSCode to view an image. An opencv window pops up displaying the image but it doesn't stay open despite the `cv2.waitKey(0)` statement. Attaching the screen recording showing the problem (Plz don't mind the screen-recording software captured in the beginning & ending).

```
import cv2
path = r'4x4_1000-25.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(path)
window_name = 'image'
cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a wsl bug: https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/58 and https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/213